# Trying to write this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from a table with this query

```
SELECT DATE( mdate ) AS mdt, u_id, d_id, COUNT(*) AS ttp, '3', a_id
FROM ar_typ
WHERE u_id >  '0'
AND a_id <> u_id
AND a_id <>  '0'
AND c_id =  '2020'
GROUP BY mdt, c_id
ORDER BY mdt ASC, u_id ASC, ttp ASC, c_id ASC
```

My PHP code works fine but having problem with MySQL. Because i know the u_id value in PHP. Let's say u_id is '10'. So u_id and a_id can not be 10. However in this MySQL code it can. Actually in PHP code instead of using `u_id > '0'` i am using `u_id = '10'` and because i want to get all data instead of one specific one, i am getting all data greater than zero.

I know this is working as expected but i just need this query return empty.

If you wonder why i am trying to get empty data, here is my actual code:

```
SELECT DATE( mdate ) AS mdt, u_id, d_id, COUNT(*) AS ttp, '3', a_id
FROM ar_typ
WHERE u_id >  '0'
AND a_id <> u_id
AND a_id <> '0'
GROUP BY mdt, c_id
ORDER BY mdt ASC, u_id ASC, ttp ASC, c_id ASC
```

I have just removed `AND c_id =  '2020'` part. It is a bit hard to explain but i hope i did.

**EDIT #1**

in another table, 2020's u_id is 10. So this query has to return everything else. I mean i know c_id's u_id from another table. I am adding this to my original question too.

Comment: mysql not equal is <>

Comment: but it still worked here

Comment: anyway i have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: are you trying to get records with u_id 1-9?

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. But I know this: you're misusing the nasty ugly MySQL extension to GROUP BY; that may be causing odd results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: in another table, 2020's u_id is 10. So this query has to return everything else. I mean i know c_id's u_id from another table. I am adding this to my original question too.